# DiagrammeR export_graph Invalid asm.js

Tags: r, export, diagrammer

I'm having a problem exporting graphs in `R` to PDFs using `DiagrammeR's` `export_graph` function in `RStudio`.

Example below to reproduce the problem. The PDFs are produced inconsistently so sometimes not at all.

The error message I get is on calling the export_graph in the code snipet below.

I'm using RStudio Version 1.1.463 and R 3.5.2 on Windows 10.

> "\<"unknown">":1919791: Invalid asm.js: Function definition doesn't
>   match use"

```
library(data.tree)
library(yaml)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(DiagrammeRsvg)

fileName <- system.file("extdata", "jennylind.yaml", package="data.tree")
cat(readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size))
lol <- yaml.load_file(fileName)
jl <- as.Node(lol)
pic <- ToDiagrammeRGraph(jl)
render_graph(pic)
export_graph(pic, "C:/Tmp/plot.pdf", file_type = "pdf")
```